# Perl 6: trans(%h) vs trans(%h.keys => %h.values)

Tags: raku

Yet another question about `hash` as argument for `trans`. In the following code taking simply `hash` gives an incorrect result, but replacing it with `keys` and `values` makes it correct. What is wrong?

```perl6
my @alph1 = <a+ b+ c+ d+ e+ f+>;
my @alph2 = <A_ B_ C_ D_ E_ F_>;
my %h;
%h{ @alph1 } = @alph2;

my $str = 'a+bc de+f';

my $text = $str.trans(%h);
say $text;    # A_BC DE_F (incorrect)

$text = $str.trans(%h.keys => %h.values);
say $text;    # A_bc dE_f (correct)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you misunderstand what `.trans` does.  You specify a range of *characters* to be changed into other *characters*.  You are NOT specifying a *string* to be changed to another *string*.

So the answer `A_BC DE_F` *is* the correct answer, because `a` is replaced by `A`, the `+` is replaced by `_`, the `b` is replaced by `B`, the `c` is replaced by `C`, etc. etc.

Perhaps we should introduce a version of `.subst` that takes a `Hash` of matchers and replacements.  Meanwhile, you will probably have to create a loop that runs over the keys/values of the hash and call `.subst` with that. (https://docs.raku.org/routine/subst)

Comment: Thank you!! But why the variant with `.trans(%h.keys => %h.values)` works?

Yes, it would be wonderful if `.subst` could take a `Hash`.

Comment: On second thought, maybe not.  If `.subst` would take a `Hash`, you would not know in which order the substitutions would be done, as the order of keys in a `Hash` is not guaranteed between versions, and possibly runs.  As to why `.trans` *does* take a `Hash`, I'm unsure, but it feels like an unintended side-effect.

Comment: Elizabeth Mattijsen, thanks! It seems that `.trans` takes a pair of `lists` and works correctly with them.