# .trans with keys longer than one symbol in Perl 6

Tags: raku

[`trans`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/trans#(Str)_method_trans) is a very useful and powerful instrument, but it remains [a bit of a mystery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46704407/7730888) for me.

E.g. I still don't understand this phrase from the docs:

> In case a list of keys and values is used, substrings can be replaced
>   as well.

What's the algorithm if keys and values are longer than one symbol?

The following test code explores how `.trans` works with 'conflicting' keys. Why does the 1st pair work differently depending on whether it is alone or accompanied by the 2nd pair?

```perl6
my Pair @trans =
     ab => '12',
     bc => '34',
     ;
my $str = 'ab';
say "both trans: $str.trans(@trans)";    # 13
say "1st  trans: $str.trans(@trans[0])"; # 12
```

Using a hash instead of a list of pairs produces a different result:

```perl6
my %trans =
     ab => '12',
     bc => '34',
     ;
my $str = 'ab';
say "both trans: $str.trans(%trans)";    # 12
```

(I understand that in `hash`, pairs can go in any sequence, but in the first example with the `list` it's the *1st* pair, which isn't fully used if the 2nd pair is present)

Answer (score 4):

(I'm not 100% sure of the following but I have to run.)

`.trans` requires one or more pair arguments that together describe the desired translation.

## Translation of *a single pair* whose key is *a single string*

P6 maps the Nth *character* of the pair's key string to the Nth *character* of the pair's value string.

Thus `.trans: "ab" => "12"` maps `"a"` to `"1"` and `"b"` to `"2"`.

## Translation of *a single pair* whose key is *a list of strings*

P6 maps the Nth *string* of the pair's key list to the Nth *string* of the pair's value list.

Thus `.trans: ("ab", "bc") => ("12", "13")` maps `"ab"` to `"12"` and `"bc"` to `"13"`.

## Translation of *a list of pairs*

Translation of a *single* pair proceeds in one or other of the two forms explained above depending on whether the key contains one string or a list of them.

Translation of a *list* of pairs just repeats the process for each pair, doing either the Nth character or Nth string mapping as per that pair's key.

> how `.trans` works with 'conflicting' keys

Given a *list* of pairs, P6 tries the first one first, and if that doesn't match, then the second pair, and so on.

---

I'll need to explore what lizmat now thinks and what she then meant when she said the following in [her earlier answer about `.trans`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46705271/1077672):

> I think you misunderstand what `.trans` does. You specify a range of characters to be changed into other characters. You are NOT specifying a string to be changed to another string.

---

I think the sentence you quoted from the doc is a bit ambiguous:

> In case a list of keys and values is used, substrings can be replaced as well.

It means that *the* (single) `.key` attribute of a pair passed to `.trans` stores a *list* of strings rather than a single string, and likewise for the pair's single `.value` attribute.

Comment: What you wrote is *very* important, so I hope you will be able to write it with more details (and examples). Thank you! Maybe it can become a blog post?..
① What if we pass a list of `Pairs`? Is it reinterpreted as a `Pair` of lists? ② Why does `.trans(%h)` work differently from `.trans(%h.keys => %values)`?

Comment: I want to check a few things before updating my answer and patching doc. As to your new questions: Q1 a list of `Pair`s? Q2 a `Pair` of lists? Q3 `.trans(%h)`? Q4 `.trans(%h.keys => %values)`? That's 2 questions, not 4 because Q3 is same as Q1 and Q4 same as Q2. The answer to Q1/Q3 is already provided in my answer -- given a list of pairs, P6 tries the first pair first, and if that doesn't match, then the second pair, and so on. Similarly, the answer to Q2/Q4 is already provided -- P6 maps the Nth string of the key to the Nth string of the value. Hopefully examples will make things clearer. :)

Comment: ...and now I've written that comment I'm immediately thinking that "first pair first" for a `Hash` (your `%h` example) is highly suspect given that ["the order of the keys and values {of a `Hash`} cannot be relied upon ... for different runs of the same program"](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Hash#Looping_over_hash_keys_and_values). Like I said, I want to check a few things...

Comment: thanks! I'm looking forward to reading an expanded version of your answer.